# Remove green border around Android application

Tags: android, css, cordova

I am currently having an issue with an Android application built with Cordova having a green frame around the body of the application:

[image: Green border issue]

It appears to be due to the web container being in focus, as the green outline disappears when an alert is shown.

This green border does not appear on the iOS version of the application, as well as in the browser or when inspecting the emulator frame using `chrome://inspect`.

I've tried multiple CSS fixes to try to remove this border such as:

```
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent !important;
  outline: none !important;
  border: 0px solid #000;
}
```

As well as disabled all accessibility settings on the devices, but to no avail.

Additional details:

- Android SDK version: 27
- Devices tested on: Nexus 5, Nexus 6, Pixel XL
- Cordova version: 3.6.4 (cannot change due to current framework requirements using MobileFirst)

Does anyone know how this issue can be resolved?

Answer (score 11):

In your

> Android/App/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

Add this item, **Inside the style tag**

```
<item name="android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled">false</item>
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding the following line to the `init` method of the `CordovaWebView` Java class under `CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/`:

```
this.setDefaultFocusHighlightEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I wonder if there's a better/proper solution?

Comment: This page says this setting became relevant in Android Oreo/8.0.  
You can change it in the layout xml file if you think keeping the visual changes in the layout xml is the way to go, instead of the way you have done it https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html

Comment: With Cordova Android 8.0.0 I had to add this line to the init method of CordovaWebViewImpl.java:
engine.getView().setDefaultFocusHighlightEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

This is because `isInTouchMode` is `true` in Cordova webview (specific to Oreo).

#### Solution

- Go to `CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaActivity.java`
- Find `appView.getView().requestFocusFromTouch();`
- Replace the above line with the following:

  ```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {
      appView.getView().requestFocusFromTouch();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove android platform
2. Add this item

```
<item name="android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled">false</item>
```

in those two files below

```
\node_modules\cordova-android\spec\fixtures\android_studio_project\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
```

and

```
\node_modules\cordova-android\test\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml
```

3. add android platform